# Simple page ordering on regular posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I´m trying to use the simple page ordering plugin on wordpress.

I get the drag & drop interface on custom post and pages but it seems that it doesn´t work with regular posts. Does anybody knows a fix to make it work with the normal wordpress posts?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-page-ordering/

Answer (score 0):

Ordering only applies to `PAGE` post type or those custom posts which are of `PAGE` type.

`POST` post type donot use ordering so the plugins also dosen't work with them

Comment: is there anyway to "hack" the post type attributes to make it work with the plugin?

Comment: @johnsharethis Please wait while i search

Comment: @johnsharethis : No there is no way you can make this plugin work for `POST` post type. But you can always change the plugin :)

Comment: yeah I have search a lot on other plugin, the only one that does something similir is the "post type order" but on the free version doesn´t lets you browse thru categories, wich doesn´t works for what I need, do you have any you have used?

Comment: @johnsharethis : No i dont have one but i have an idea. use metabox for ordering on posts and then use filter to change the wp_query to use the meta_value for the sorting